# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, closing

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/where-can-i-find-serious-teammates-in-modern-warfare-2-closed

I understand that there is a risk of subjective answers, such as `X clan is awesome` and so forth, but isn't that why the se system works? If someone posted that kind of an answer, it would be downvoted heavily.  There are objective answers/pieces of advice which work for this question, (see my comment).

Comment: We had a discussion about this on chat. We decided it was too subjective to leave open, plus it was too open-ended as is.

Comment: @Arda Some more detail as to how you people came to that conclusion would be nice "Oh, we had a discussion" doesn't really answer the "why". What elements made you all think it was too subjective and open-ended?

Comment: What I said, it's too open-ended. The answers would mostly be a list of clans to join. There's way too much of those to answer the question properly.

Comment: @Adra I think our discussion was a little more in depth than you seem to be portraying, I'll try ti write up a little more as an answer later.